# pow(0, 2.2) gives 1 in a hlsl pixel shader?

Tags: math, shader, hlsl, pixel-shader

But pow(0, 2.0) gives 0

Seems that any float exponent gives 1 while integer exponents give 0.

I am using DirectX 9 and hlsl compiler "D3DCompiler_43.dll".
Confirmed that on Nvidia and Ati cards.

I am confused!
Is that some kind of known behaviour or bug?

To illustrate the effect try the following simple test shader:

```
// Test shader demonstrating strange pow behaviour
// when brightness becomes 0 resulting color will jump to white

float4x4 WorldViewProjXf : WorldViewProjection < string UIWidget="None";>;

float Brightness
<
    string UIName = "Brightness";   
    float UIMin =  0;   
    float UIMax =  1;       
> = 0;


struct VS_Input
{
    float4 position : POSITION0;
};

struct VS_Output
{
    float4 position : POSITION0;
};

VS_Output Vertex_Func( VS_Input in_data )
{
    VS_Output outData;
    outData.position = mul(in_data.position, WorldViewProjXf);
    return outData;
}

float4 Fragment_Func( VS_Output in_data ) : COLOR
{
    return pow(Brightness, 2.2);
}

technique Main 
{
    pass p0 
    {       
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 Vertex_Func();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 Fragment_Func();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the HLSL docs, `pow(x, y)` appears to be implemented directly as `exp(y * log(x))`.  Since `x=0` in your question, again looking at the docs `log(x) == -INF`.  It seems like the value of `y` shouldn't matter at that point as long as it's positive and greater than zero.

You might be accidentally comparing `pow(0.0, 2.0) == 0.0` with `pow(0.0, 0.0) == 1.0`.  That's my best guess for what's happening.

[`log(0)=-INF` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[`pow = exp(y * log(x))` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Could you please post a link to those docs you are speaking of. Sounds better than the informations I could find on msdn.

Comment: Added references.  The second reference is to the `pow` instruction, rather than the `pow` intrinsic function.

Comment: Now I see, you were talking about the shader assembler docs. Not HLSL but somewhat helpful as there is some additional info. Its right, "pow(abs(Color), Exponent)" and "exp(Exponent * log(Color))" all give the same result - including the zero-bug, unfortunately. Well, your answer is not exactly an answer but as far as there is no other and you were helpful you get the checkmark.